# In Debian Jessie apache2-dev package is missing aspx2

Tags: apache2, debian-jessie

I have verified that I have installed the latest apache2, apache2-bin, apache2-dev, apache2-mpm-prefork, apache2-utils, apache2.2-bin, and apache2.2-common. The apache2-dev package is supposed to include aspx2 located in /usr/bin, but it's not there.

I removed and reinstalled apache2-dev, but aspx2 is still not being installed on my system. If you know how to resolve this issue, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mean apxs (APache eXtenSion tool) ?

If so, the filename is /usr/bin/apxs and it exists in apache2-dev
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/apache2-dev/filelist

If not please list files of this package with 
    dpkg -L apache2-dev